# Why can't evince open this pdf issued by my bank while adobe pdf reader can?

Tags: pdf, evince, adobe-acrobat

When I'm trying out a PDF which is a form fill PDF given to me by my bank for signing up to a business account Evince (3.26.0) just shows me the following

[image]

Which is not very helpful. I waited for 10 minutes and still nothing so I don't believe the Please wait instruction is the way to go..

Interestingly enough, libreoffice 5.4 could open it. Any ideas of what to do?

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 and Linux einstein 4.14.12-041412-generic #201801051649 SMP Fri Jan 5 16:50:54 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Did you check if the "real" PDF is embedded as an attachment?

Comment: Which question do you want to ask, why can't evince open it or "what to do". If the later then: what to do about what? If you launch evince from a command line do you get errors, can you open the document in a text-editor?

Comment: Whomever voted to close this as off topic, it is not off topic. The question is about a piece of software in Ubuntu. The problem is XFA forms which are deprecated, but which for some reason, are appearing more often these days.

Comment: @pbhj Evince from command line opens fine. No warnings. I know what to do. I already solved it. I'm just wondering why Adobe and LibreOffice draw can open the file but evince cannot.